# NIVO slider light text disappears

Tags: jquery, wordpress, nivo-slider

I am using NIVO slider light plugin in wordpress. [here](http://5pillarsgame.com/)

The text comes on the slider as expected. Open a new tab and after a while come back to the website and you won't see the text but the slider still runs.

What I found is that jquery sets the section's opacity to zero! Why is it setting to zero?

Comment: in which web browser did you experience this?

Comment: Im experiencing this issue in all browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on my website, until I upgraded the JQuery from 1.6.1 to 1.7. It seems like that fixed it.